# How to pull decimal value from database using Node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, nan

So I am using an eBay's API to pull items to our website and would like to convert the price that is pulled to what our "Sponsors" conversion rate is for the purpose of changing to a point system instead of dollars and cents.  For example if their conversion rate .01 then a $12.50 item should be 1250 points.  The output of the following code results in "NaN" being displayed which I am aware means Not a Number so I am trying to figure out the best way to get the conversion rate value to be able to correctly calculate the new value.

```
    request(options, function (error, response) {
      if (error) throw new Error(error);
      var parseItem = JSON.parse(response.body);
      var itemArray = [parseItem.itemSummaries[0].image, parseItem.itemSummaries[0].title, parseItem.itemSummaries[0].price, parseItem.itemSummaries[0].itemWebUrl];

      itemArray[0] = queryString.stringify(itemArray[0]);
      itemArray[0] = itemArray[0].substring(9);
      itemArray[0] = decodeURIComponent(itemArray[0]);

      itemArray[2] = queryString.stringify(itemArray[2]);
      itemArray[2] = parseFloat(itemArray[2]);
      connection.query("SELECT * FROM Sponsor WHERE UserId = ?;", [userID],function(error, SponsorInfo, fields) {
        if (error) throw (error);
        var conversionRate = connection.query('SELECT PointConversion FROM Sponsor WHERE UserId = ?;', [userID], function(error, count, fields) {
          console.log(conversionRate);
          console.log(itemArray[2]);
        
          itemArray[2] = itemArray[2] / conversionRate;
          console.log(itemArray[2]);
          if (error) throw error;
            response.redirect('/sponsor_catalog');
        })
      })
```

Comment: What does `console.log(conversionRate)` show you?Might you need to parse it to be a number?

Comment: 27|Sprint1 |       _queue: [Array],
27|Sprint1 |       _handshakeInitializationPacket: [HandshakeInitializationPacket],
27|Sprint1 |       _parser: [Parser],
27|Sprint1 |       [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
27|Sprint1 |     },
27|Sprint1 |     _connectCalled: true,
27|Sprint1 |     state: 'authenticated',
27|Sprint1 |     threadId: 18953,
27|Sprint1 |     [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
27|Sprint1 |   },
27|Sprint1 |   [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
27|Sprint1 | }

Comment: I definitely know that how I have it is wrong and just need to know how to get the value back in a form that is useful as a decimal

Comment: parseFloat doesn't deal with non numeric/period characters - what is the string value being passed into it? If it contains a pretty human-readable value, then any currency indicators and any commas would needs stripped first.

Either that or the other floaty number in your code is conversionRate. But console.log isn't going to give NaN so I think it's with the itemArray strings that represent numbers failing to parse. IIRC if the first character passed into parseFloat is a digit, then it won't give NaN, it will just stop at the first non-numeric - but if the first character is eg $, then NaN

Comment: Ahh, you;re not getting an error, you're getting NaN from your console logs? Sorry, I'm prob barking up the wrong tree then! Do a console.log(parseFloat(arrayItem[2])) and see what you get?

Comment: I just noticed, that `conversionRate` is the query with a callback function. Wouldn't the callback parameters contain the selected rows? Why do you set a variable like that? What are you using to do the query?

Comment: So I added this line to clean up everything except decimals and numbers "itemArray[2] = itemArray[2].replace(/[^\.-]/g, '');" So now the parseFloat works correctly I believe but to answer you Geshode that was the only way I could think to get the conversion value from our database which I know is wrong but that's really the main reason I posted this was to figure out how to get that value in a decimal value to be able to convert it in this file.